# Could not find the GEOS library

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-forms

i am working on a simple employee listing Django application. i wanted to include filtering in my app, so tried installing django-filter module. i think django-filter is not installed properly ( i am not going to use it anyway). But after doing this, when i try to run my application, it gives this ,

```
"`ViewDoesNotExist at /employeeList/` ;
Could not import task.employeeDetails.views. Error was: Could not find the GEOS library (tried "geos_c", "GEOS"). Try setting GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings "
```

. while i searched for the error,came to know the error is due to some wrong geoDjango installation. But i dont need geoDjango and i am wondering how its throwing this error. Before doing this, my app was working fine. Somebody please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to check:

1. Are you using the GeoDjango database classes? If your database engine is set to something like `django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis` or `django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql`, those are the geo backends. What you want is something like `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2` or `django.db.backends.mysql`. Not the lack of the "contrib.gis" part.
2. The other most likely possibility is that `task.employeeDetails.views` is importing or running something that requires GEOS.